# Java evaluate XPath against a org.w3c.dom.Node

Tags: java, xpath

Dipping my toe in a little Java at the minute and have a question about XPath.

I have a large Xml and I want to use XPath to be able to grab a specific node and then fire further XPath calls against this small chunk of Xml.

Here s rough outline of my Xml:

```
<Page>
  <ComponentPresentations>
    <ComponentPresentation>
      <Component>
        <Title>
      <ComponentTemplate> 
    <ComponentPresentation>
      <Component>
        <Title>
      <ComponentTemplate>
```

My first XPath selects the `<Component>` node based upon the value of a `<ComponenTemplate>` Id value:

```
String componentExpFormat = "/Page/ComponentPresentations/ComponentPresentation/ComponentTemplate/Id[text()='%1$s']/ancestor::ComponentPresentation";
String componentExp = String.format(componentExpFormat, template);
XPathExpression expComponent = xPath.compile(componentExp);
Node componentXml = (Node) expComponent.evaluate(xmldoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

This gives me the `<Component>` I want but I can;t seem to be able to then XPath against the Node:

```
String componentExpTitle = "/Component/Fields/item/value/Field/Name[text()='title']/parent::node()/Values/string";                                  
XPathExpression expTitle = xPath.compile(componentExpTitle);
String eventName = expTitle.evaluate(componentXml, XPathConstants.STRING).toString();
```

Without this I'll have to include the full XPath each time:

```
/Page/ComponentPresentations/ComponentPresentation/ComponentTemplate/Id[text()='%1$s']/ancestor::ComponentPresentation/Component/Fields/item/value/Field/Name[text()='title']/parent::node()/Values/string
```

Is that the only way?

Cheers

Comment: Your `componentExpTitle` is an absolute path, remove the leading slash and try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XPath expression with a leading slash

```
/Component/Fields/item
```

is *absolute*, and when you evaluate it with a particular context node it will start looking from the root of the document that the context node belongs to.  If you remove the leading slash

```
Component/Fields/item
```

it will look for `Component` children of the context node.

As an aside, you can simplify those XPaths quite a bit, you don't need all the up and down the tree stuff with `ancestor::`, and you also don't need to use `text()`:

```
componentExpFormat = "/Page/ComponentPresentations/ComponentPresentation[ComponentTemplate/Id='%1$s']";
componentExpTitle = "Component/Fields/item/value/Field[Name='title']/Values/string";
```

Comment: Ian, if SO would let me vote more than once I would because you my friend have made the next couple of hours waaaay easier for me - and I've improved my XPath along the way! Cheers!